# ggplot: In geom_tile, how to use a variable designates the groups instead of the individual id's on x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have some data of this form:

```
                                        ID2                                   ID1      value         pop1         pop2
1     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam 16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam 0.00000000        Maine        Maine
2     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam        out_17SPL07-16-POOL-ExoSAP_S34 0.03231083        Maine        Maine
3     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam   17LHR07-57-POOL_S49_L001_merged.bam 0.03231083     Maryland        Maine
4     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam   17LHR07-53-POOL_S47_L001_merged.bam 0.03231083     Maryland        Maine
5     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam   17LHR07-30-POOL_S43_L001_merged.bam 0.03231083     Maryland        Maine
6     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam    18In08-39-POOL_S75_L001_merged.bam 0.00000000 Pennsylvania        Maine
7     16EME10-CP109-POOL_S1_L001_merged.bam        out_17SPL07-11-POOL-ExoSAP_S29 0.05430377        Maine        Maine
........
```

When I draw the heatmap using geom tile:

```
ggplot(fstnewm, aes(ID1, ID2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color =   "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

it puts each of the IDs of the axis. I want to group the data using `pop1` and `pop2` while keeping individual tiles and have these groups on both of the axes. I assume I should use `geom_text`, however, I couldn't find how.

Edit:
[Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moXbA.png)
In this graph I want to keep individual comparisons, however, have the populations in the both axes, instead of the ids of the samples.

Comment: Could you include an example of a similar plot? I can't tell what you're trying to get—group how? and do what with the groups? and put what in the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_x_discrete` or/and `scale_y_discrete` to change the labels on the axes.

```
ggplot(fstnewm, aes(ID1, ID2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color =   "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = fstnewm$ID1,
                   labels = fstnewm$pop1) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = fstnewm$ID2,
                   labels = fstnewm$pop2)
```